# py2exe windows file system distribution

Tags: windows, py2exe

I am trying to create an application which I want later on to distribute.
When I make the executable with py2exe I get the following warning message:

```
Make sure you have the license if you distribute any of them, and
make sure you don't distribute files belonging to the operating system.

OLEAUT32.dll - C:\Windows\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
USER32.dll - C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
IMM32.dll - C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.dll
SHELL32.dll - C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll
ole32.dll - C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
WINMM.dll - C:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll
COMDLG32.dll - C:\Windows\system32\COMDLG32.dll
ADVAPI32.dll - C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
WS2_32.dll - C:\Windows\system32\WS2_32.dll
WINSPOOL.DRV - C:\Windows\system32\WINSPOOL.DRV
GDI32.dll - C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
VERSION.dll - C:\Windows\system32\VERSION.dll
KERNEL32.dll - C:\Windows\system32\KERNEL32.dll
```

All these files appear to be preinstalled in the operating system. If I excude them from the .exe will every user of the programme  have them installed in their system?

Also about dlls like MSVCP90.dll, which I have already excluded, what's the best way to include mamke them available to the user? Should I use an installer for the job? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The listed DLL:s contain the implementation Windows API. If the user has installed Windows, these files will be installed. MSVCP is not a part of Windows API. It seams like you can add it to an installer or refer to the Microsoft website:

> SLADE 3.1.0 requires the 32-bit Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Runtimes (x86) to be installed, which can be downloaded here: Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Runtime.
>   Note that the SLADE installer will automatically download and install this when installing SLADE.